# Is there a way to find optimal sensor node locations in a domain when all data is known?

Tags: experiment-design, covariance, spatial, variogram, kriging

I have an x-y domain where I know the snow depth everywhere. (i.e. the granularity of the values is such that I can assume I know it everywhere).

I want to use this information to inform where to place sensor nodes for the most informative sensing.  I have 10 sensor nodes that I want to place across this domain.

I know how to use `kriging` and other methods to estimate a variable that varies spatially.  But, how do I use my knowledge of the ground truth *everywhere* to test where are the best locations for the sensor nodes?

Assumptions:

- the sensor nodes can sense only one point accurately, not a radius.
- connectivity is not an issue

**EDIT**

My intuition tells me the following:

- it's probably a good idea to concentrate more sensors around areas where the variation in the observed values is high, and fewer sensors in areas where the observed values do not vary too much.  But, how do I quantify this?  I also want to caution against overfitting here....

Comment: Sounds like a variant of [optimal experimental design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design). If you don't mind over-fitting to this *particular* ground truth, you could even run an optimization to minimize area-integrated misfit by varying the 10 sample locations. More commonly though, locations would be chosen based on some more general criterion (commonly data-independent, e.g. avoid [high-leverage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics))).

Comment: @GeoMatt22, thanks. "Optimal experimental design" is a bit vague.  The independent variable here is the x, y location, so i'm not sure I follow you why avoiding those would work....Do you mind elaborating a bit on these principles?  Also, please see my edits incorporated into the question.

Comment: The link I provided gives an overview, but as I understand it "optimal experimental design" means you are optimizing some statistic that is a function of the experimental setup (i.e. *not* a function of the experimental results, in the usual case). For example, in a linear regression framework, the optimal might try to minimize the potential influence of outliers by placing the independent-variable samples to optimize the ["hat matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix).

Comment: In response to your update: Say you are using kriging. In the simplest case, let us assume that your variogram is known and fixed. Then given some placement of $n$ sensors, you could compute a map of the kriging variance, and place sensor $n+1$ at the location with maximum variance. In your case, you could calibrate the variogram based on the ground truth. (In a real case, you might consider placement of sensors to ensure a confident asessment of the variogram, e.g. based on the distribution of inter-sensor lag vectors.) BTW if these comments are useful (?), I can combine them into an answer.

Comment: Yes, these are helping me get closer....thanks.  I totally understand that I could calibrate the variogram based on the ground truth data.  But, to start, the `n` sensors are literally at every location on the domain, so you can't really place an `n+1` sensor since there would be no room.  Your idea about placing the sensors to ensure confident assessment of the variogram is brilliant.  I'd really like to hear more about that.  Rather than assessing based on prediction error, your assessing based on error in estimating the variogram?

Comment: I will have to think about this. To ensure this gets seen by folks who may know more, you might add the [design of experiments tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experiment-design) to your question.